# How to get QueryString value in Infopath forms

Tags: c#, infopath

When my Infopath form loaded in the query string i will get the value. I would like to retrieve the value of a query string parameter. How can I do that in Infopath's form code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/26/passing-data-into-a-form-input-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Several solutions:

- [How to Pass Querystring data into an InfoPath Form](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form.aspx)
- [Passing Data into a Form: Input Parameters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/26/passing-data-into-a-form-input-parameters.aspx)

Taking information from those two links the Infopath form code is pretty easy for the URL:

```
public void FormEvents_Loading(object sender, LoadingEventArgs e)
{
   string qryValue = e.InputParameters["MyQueryValue"];
   //qryValue would return 1 for the URL "http://www.blabla.com/myform.xsn?MyQueryValue=1"
}
```